# .net clr internal error 80131506

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, interop, clr

I have an ASP.NET web app that is crashing out multiple times a day. When the crash happens there is an event log entry saying:

> Application: w3wp.exe Framework Version v4.0.30319 The process was
>   terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP
>   00007FF88B6033A8 (00007FF88B5A0000) with exit code 80131506.

I believe this error started happening when I switched the app to running in 64-bit mode (by setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to False on the app pool in IIS). The application targets .Net 4.5.2 and all the projects in the solution are built for "Any CPU". The servers that the app is running on have .Net 4.7.1 installed.

We've captured memory dumps using DebugDiag and identified a suspect call stack:

```
Entry point   clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc 
Create time   8/14/2018 5:21:12 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:07.171 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 00:00:00.812 


This thread is attempting to make a .NET Remoting call, however they do *not* appear to be waiting on the remote server to respond (eg. not 'on the wire')

 Remote URI:/879d6089_07f9_4237_bee6_a35a44ba1a01/op7suowikn1m+i3lqmgtwx_a_302.rem

The thread has evidence of .net exceptions on the stack. Check the Previous .NET Exceptions Report (Exceptions in all .NET Thread Stacks) to view more details of the associated exception  





.NET Call Stack




[[HelperMethodFrame]] 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+458 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.ServerObjectTerminatorSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+ae 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.ServerContextTerminatorSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+fc 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossContextChannel.SyncProcessMessageCallback(System.Object[])+171 
[[HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ] (System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback)] System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, IntPtr, Int32, System.Threading.InternalCrossContextDelegate, System.Object[]) 
System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, System.Threading.InternalCrossContextDelegate, System.Object[])+3c 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossContextChannel.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+ac 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.SyncDispatchMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+bc 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[], System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage ByRef)+cb 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(System.Object[])+96 
[[ContextTransitionFrame]] 
[[HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ] (System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback)] System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, IntPtr, Int32, System.Threading.InternalCrossContextDelegate, System.Object[]) 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatch(Byte[], System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage ByRef)+a5 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+ce 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.CallProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.ArrayWithSize, System.Threading.Thread, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, Boolean)+aa 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.InternalInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage, Boolean, Int32)+39a 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData ByRef, Int32)+383 
[[TPMethodFrame] (System.Collections.Generic.IList.get_Item)] System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExpressionHostObjectModel.TextBoxExprHost, Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel]].get_Item(Int32) 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.TextBox.SetExprHost(Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExpressionHostObjectModel.ReportExprHost, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.ObjectModelImpl)+8c 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext.RuntimeInitializeTextboxObjs(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.ReportItem, Boolean)+4e 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.OnDemandPageEvaluation.InitializeEnvironment()+39c 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.Report..ctor(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Report, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.ReportInstance, Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.RenderingContext, System.String, System.String)+9a 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReportOdp.PrepareROM(Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.RenderingContext ByRef)+c8 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReport.Execute(Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.IRenderingExtension)+17d 
Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Render(System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean, System.Collections.IEnumerable, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream)+2dc 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(System.String, Boolean, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] ByRef)+12d 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalModeSession.RenderReport(System.String, Boolean, System.String, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, Boolean, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)+132 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.ViewerRenderer+SPBProcessingStub.GetNextPage(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RPLProcessing.RPLReport ByRef)+257 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HTML4Renderer.GetNextPage()+23 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HTML4Renderer.InitializeReport()+15 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.ViewerRenderer.Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)+14 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalHtmlRenderer.Render(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControlSession, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)+13d 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControlSession.RenderReportHTML4(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)+8f 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControl.RenderReport(Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControlSession, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, Int32, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.InteractivityPostBackMode, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SearchState, System.String, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ScrollTarget, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.DeviceInfoCollection, System.String, Boolean)+127 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportArea.RenderReport(Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControlSession, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, Int32, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.InteractivityPostBackMode, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SearchState, System.String, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ScrollTarget, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.DeviceInfoCollection, System.String, Boolean)+ab 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.RenderReport(Boolean)+136 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.OnPreRender(System.EventArgs)+4dd 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+c8 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean, Boolean)+ddb 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean, Boolean)+ab 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()+4b 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)+7e 
System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()+2bb 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep)+d8 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)+5b 
System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)+699 
System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback)+8b 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext)+1a0 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+451 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+13 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int32)+52 
[[ContextTransitionFrame]] 

Full Call Stack




ntdll!NtTerminateProcess 
ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+60 
kernel32!ExitProcessImplementation+a 
mscoreei!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes+287 
mscoreei!CLRRuntimeHostInternalImpl::ShutdownAllRuntimesThenExit+14 
clr!EEPolicy::ExitProcessViaShim+95 
clr!SafeExitProcess+9d 
clr!EEPolicy::HandleFatalError+123 
clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerPhase3+34ade6 
clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerPhase2+2d 
clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandler+94 
clr!CLRVectoredExceptionHandlerShim+a3 
ntdll!RtlpCallVectoredHandlers+e6 
ntdll!RtlDispatchException+63 
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+3a 
clr!CMiniMdTemplate<CMiniMdRW>::getNamespaceOfTypeDef+38 
clr!RegMeta::GetTypeDefProps+19c 
ClrProfInstrumProbe+ab30 
ClrProfInstrumProbe+2cf69 
ClrProfInstrumProbe!DllInstall+8ab4 
ClrProfInstrumProbe!DllInstall+906f 
ClrProfInstrumProbe!DllInstall+b8e6 
ClrProfInstrumProbe!DllInstall+b6d4 
ClrProfInstrumProbe!DllInstall+bd0e 
ClrProfInstrumProbe!DllInstall+31c40 
ClrProfInstrumProbe!DllInstall+2dec9 
ClrProfInstrumProbe!DllInstall+2b50c 
ClrProfInstrumProbe!boost::archive::detail::oserializer<portable_binary_oarchive,DebugLog::FrontEnd::LineNumber>::save_object_data+b922a 
clr!ProfileLeave+1dd 
[[HelperMethodFrame]] 
clr!ProfileLeaveNaked+6e 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+458 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.ServerObjectTerminatorSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+ae 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.ServerContextTerminatorSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+fc 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossContextChannel.SyncProcessMessageCallback(System.Object[])+171 
clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+83 
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+4e 
clr!DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper+1f 
clr!DispatchCallSimple+93 
clr!ThreadNative::InternalCrossContextCallback+340 
[[HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ] (System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback)] System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, IntPtr, Int32, System.Threading.InternalCrossContextDelegate, System.Object[]) 
System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, System.Threading.InternalCrossContextDelegate, System.Object[])+3c 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossContextChannel.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+ac 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.SyncDispatchMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+bc 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[], System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage ByRef)+cb 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(System.Object[])+96 
clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+83 
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+4e 
clr!DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper+1f 
clr!DispatchCallSimple+93 
clr!ThreadNative::InternalCrossContextCallback+340 
[[ContextTransitionFrame]] 
[[HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ] (System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback)] System.Threading.Thread.InternalCrossContextCallback(System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, IntPtr, Int32, System.Threading.InternalCrossContextDelegate, System.Object[]) 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatch(Byte[], System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage ByRef)+a5 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)+ce 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.CallProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.ArrayWithSize, System.Threading.Thread, System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context, Boolean)+aa 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.InternalInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage, Boolean, Int32)+39a 
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData ByRef, Int32)+383 
clr!CTPMethodTable__CallTargetHelper3+12 
clr!CallTargetWorker2+85 
clr!TransparentProxyStubWorker+1dea7 
[[TPMethodFrame] (System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExpressionHostObjectModel.TextBoxExprHost>.get_Item)] System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExpressionHostObjectModel.TextBoxExprHost, Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel]].get_Item(Int32) 
clr!TransparentProxyStub_CrossContext+55 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.TextBox.SetExprHost(Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExpressionHostObjectModel.ReportExprHost, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.ObjectModelImpl)+8c 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandProcessing.OnDemandProcessingContext.RuntimeInitializeTextboxObjs(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.ReportItem, Boolean)+4e 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.OnDemandPageEvaluation.InitializeEnvironment()+39c 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.Report..ctor(Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.Report, Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportIntermediateFormat.ReportInstance, Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.RenderingContext, System.String, System.String)+9a 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReportOdp.PrepareROM(Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.RenderingContext ByRef)+c8 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReport.Execute(Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.IRenderingExtension)+17d 
Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Render(System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean, System.Collections.IEnumerable, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream)+2dc 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(System.String, Boolean, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] ByRef)+12d 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalModeSession.RenderReport(System.String, Boolean, System.String, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, Boolean, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)+132 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.ViewerRenderer+SPBProcessingStub.GetNextPage(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RPLProcessing.RPLReport ByRef)+257 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HTML4Renderer.GetNextPage()+23 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HTML4Renderer.InitializeReport()+15 
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.ViewerRenderer.Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)+14 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalHtmlRenderer.Render(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControlSession, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.CreateAndRegisterStream, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)+13d 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControlSession.RenderReportHTML4(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, System.String ByRef, System.String ByRef)+8f 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControl.RenderReport(Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControlSession, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, Int32, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.InteractivityPostBackMode, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SearchState, System.String, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ScrollTarget, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.DeviceInfoCollection, System.String, Boolean)+127 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportArea.RenderReport(Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportControlSession, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.PageCountMode, Int32, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.InteractivityPostBackMode, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SearchState, System.String, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ScrollTarget, System.String, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.DeviceInfoCollection, System.String, Boolean)+ab 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.RenderReport(Boolean)+136 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer.OnPreRender(System.EventArgs)+4dd 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+c8 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()+129 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean, Boolean)+ddb 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean, Boolean)+ab 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()+4b 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)+7e 
System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()+2bb 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep)+d8 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)+5b 
System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception)+699 
System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback)+8b 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext)+1a0 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+451 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32)+13 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int64, Int64, Int64, Int32)+52 
clr!UM2MThunk_WrapperHelper+43 
clr!UM2MThunk_Wrapper+60 
clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+13d 
[[ContextTransitionFrame]] 
clr!UM2MDoADCallBack+b3 
clr!UMThunkStub+26d 
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ProcessNotification+8e 
webengine4!ProcessNotificationCallback+42 
clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+1bc 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+64 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+f5 
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+86 
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+22 
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+34
```

I picked through the dump with WinDbg and found the exception:

```
0:104> !PrintException /d 00000060079b11f8
Exception object: 00000060079b11f8
Exception type:   System.ExecutionEngineException
Message:          <none>
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
<none>
StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131506
```

That exception is basically just the generic exception that is showing up in our event log, with no message, inner exception, or stack trace.

Also when I run !EEStack I get this stack for the suspect thread: https://pastebin.com/KbnM5MP2 (too long to paste here). It looks like the exception is coming in during some clr jit activity, but I don't know what that might mean.

We've tried disabling concurrent garbage collection by setting `<gcConcurrent enabled="false" />` in our web.config, but that didn't help one bit.

It looks like the exception could be originating from something related to Microsoft Reporting. Upon inspection, it looks like our app is using v12 of the MS Reporting libraries, which are pretty dated. So I might consider updating those libraries to v14.

I could use some help on how to proceed with this issue. I'll probably contact MS Support today, but I thought I'd throw this on here to see what ideas you guys and gals might have.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: I think the issue was caused by one of the monitoring apps on the server... Solar Winds or something like that. That app was always present in the crashing callstack somewhere. Removing it fixed the issue.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky, I don't think so. We ended up scheduling an app restart every morning. Our app eventually was retired about a year ago, so it isn't an issue any longer.